# How to write log file while debugging in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

How to write  log file while debugging in dolphindb?

I want to save some record in dolphindb log file when I debug some scripts. Is there any methods to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

The function “writeLog(X1, [X2, X3....Xn])” in DolphinDB can write the information to the log file which you want to output for debugging.
The sample code is as follows:

```py
writeLog("This is a message written into the log file.")
writeLog("line1.","line2.","line3");
```

Check the log file:

```py
Sun Aug 06 16:41:05 2020 <INFO> :This is a message written into the log file.
Sun Aug 06 16:50:35 2020 <INFO> :line1.
Sun Aug 06 16:50:35 2020 <INFO> :line2.
Sun Aug 06 16:50:35 2020 <INFO> :line3
```